# Getting error that invalid column name while writing SQL statement in Python

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, parameters, dateadd

I am trying to write a SQL statement in Python: 'attribute' is a column name that I want to change its format and I am giving it as a parameter. Because its name can be different.

```
cur.execute("SELECT DATEADD(y," + attribute + ", '1980-01-01')")
```

But I am getting below error. attribute=Date1 and this column exists.

> [42S22] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'Date1'. (207) (SQLExecDirectW)"

Comment: Your query has no table. It needs a `from`. `select dateadd(...) FROM some_table`. Also be sure to use bind parameters rather than string concatenation to add values to a SQL query; see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902408/how-to-use-variables-in-sql-statement-in-python

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If I understand your code correctly, you're building the string in the `cur.execute` command. If your python is up-to-date, try using [fstrings](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/formatted-string-literals-f-strings-python/). They are a bit more readable and you don't get the messy code with all the quotes. If your python version doesn't support substrings, try building the request in a variable to make the code a bit more readable. 
 Possible solution: 
 `cur.execute(f"SELECT DATEADD(y, {attribute}, '1980-01-01')")`

 The string will result in `SELECT DATEADD(y, Date1, '1980-01-01')`

 There is also a `FROM` missing from the query, the error `Invalid column` is correct because you don't tell where to find that column